# Problem with cipher showing doubled letters c++

Tags: c++, encryption

I have a little problem with my code. This should change every letter to some other i.e "a to g" etc. Everything is good but at the end the letters "u, v, w, x, y, z" are changed to "k, l, m, n, o, p" same as "a, b, c, d, e, f". I spent like 5 hours to find the problem and still don't know what to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


int test(int a)
{
    if(a==1){
        return a;
    }
        return a - test(a-1);
}


char ciph(char *arr, int a)
{
    int lenght = strlen(arr);

    for(int i=0;i<lenght && arr[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(arr[i]))
        {
            if (arr[i]<=122 && arr[i]>=113)
            {
                 arr[i]=arr[i]-test(a);
            }

            else
            {
                 arr[i]=arr[i]+test(a);
            }

        }
    }

    std::cout << arr << std::endl;


}

int main()
{
    int b=19;
    char arr[100];
    std::cin.getline(arr, 100);
    std::cout << ciph(arr, b) << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: " but at the end the letters "u, v, w, x, y, z" are changed to "k, l, m, n, o, p"" what else should happen? PLease include actual and desired output

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will help tremendously.

Comment: 1. What should happen instead?
2. Should be `void ciph(yadda)` if you are modifying arr in-place using pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This should change every letter to some other i.e "a to g" etc. Everything is good but at the end the letters "u, v, w, x, y, z" are changed to "k, l, m, n, o, p" same as "a, b, c, d, e, f".

Consider these lines of code

```
if (arr[i]<=122 && arr[i]>=113)
{ //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    arr[i]=arr[i]-test(a);
}

else
{
    arr[i]=arr[i]+test(a);
}
```

You can rewrite those as (assumning an ASCII encoding):

```
if ( 'K' <= arr[i]  &&  arr[i] <= 'R' )
{ // ^^^                          ^^^       
    arr[i] -= test(a);
}
else
{
    arr[i] += test(a);
}
```

Note that `'R'` is different from `'r'`. If your test case contains only lower case letters, the first branch will never be executed.

In general, you should avoid magic numbers like `122` and use a standard container like `std::string`.